# Symfony Expression Has_role issue even though user has role

Tags: symfony, roles

In my user has ADMIN and AUTEUR role, when I try to reach a page which need those roles, I have this error:

Expression "has_role('ROLE_AUTEUR')" denied access.
403 Forbidden

the user's "role" field in bd:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:10:"ROLE_ADMIN";i:1;s:11:"ROLE_AUTEUR";}
```

security.yml

```
role_hierarchy:

    # app/config/security.yml
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_AUTEUR, ROLE_MODERATEUR]       # Un admin hérite des droits d'auteur et de modérateur
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH] # On garde ce rôle superadmin, il nous resservira par la suite
```

the controller:

```
    /**
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_AUTEUR')")
 */
public function addAction(Request $request) {

    /* METHODE SECURITY avec SECURITY.CONTEXT
     * 

    // On vérifie que l'utilisateur dispose bien du rôle ROLE_AUTEUR
    if (!$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_AUTEUR')) {
        // Sinon on déclenche une exception « Accès interdit »
        throw new AccessDeniedException('Accès limité aux auteurs.');
    }
    */

    $advert = new Advert ();

    // VERSION LONGUE
    // $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new AdvertType(), $advert);
    $form = $this->createForm ( new AdvertType (), $advert );

    if ($form->handleRequest ( $request )->isValid ()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine ()->getManager ();
        $em->persist ( $advert );
        $em->flush ();

        $request->getSession ()->getFlashBag ()->add ( 'notice', 'Annonce bien enregistrée.' );

        return $this->redirect ( $this->generateUrl ( 'oc_platform_view', array (
                'id' => $advert->getId () 
        ) ) );
    }

    return $this->render ( 'OCPlatformBundle:Advert:add.html.twig', array (
            'form' => $form->createView () 
    ) );
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: It seems that current user has not ADMIN_ROLE neither ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong but the annotation only sais he needs ROLE_AUTEUR...I edited the question with the role field in db

Comment: How about "access_control" entry in security.yml? You must provide a full file content of security.yml.

Comment: Only:
       - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }